# Javascript - why my example alerts 1 instead of 10?

Tags: javascript

My sample code:

```js
var foo = 1;
function bar() {
 foo = 10;
 return;
 function foo() {}
}
bar();
alert(foo);
```

Why does it alert 1? I am expecting 10.
However if I comment out function foo(){} after return, it does return 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declarations inside other functions are treated as if they appeared at the very start of the containing function. That is, your `bar()` function is treated as if it looked like:

```
function bar() {
    function foo() {}
    foo = 10;
    return;
}
```

Thus `foo` is a *local* symbol in the function, and assignment to it does not affect the global `foo`.

Comment: Please just vote to close instead of answering. This *exact* question comes up quite often